# bootstrap structure and best practices

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey I building an app these days for company at NY.
I need my app to be fully responsive, this means that in any given layout the app should be appears in a good shape.
Now there are several ways for creating a responsive site or app, one of the common ways is using bootstrap as a fluid grid. The problem is that bootstrap doesn't give me a really full solution to all of my needs and probably I am using it the wrong way.
Now I will explain how a screen in my app is look like.
The main screen is **divided** to 3 rows, each row contain 3 squares, each square is a **container** for 3 different tables. 
My problem start when I am trying to decide about the right bootstrap structure for this layout so it will be the most responsive.
For single box I am using the following structure

```
container-fluid
   row
    col-xs-10 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4
      title
       container-fluid
          row 
            col-md-6 col-lg-6
             table1
            col-md-6 col-lg-6
              table2
          row
            col-lg-12
             table3
```

now I have a couple of questions:

1. Is this the right structure when using bootstrap for introducing a box with 3 tables.
2. I have a problem of overlapping of content which overlap other content which sits near him.
3. How can I use the formula target/context = result to achieve more responsive layout?

The overlapping problem:
[image]
The full code is here:

http://codepen.io/Barak/pen/dMKYbe

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("mainCTRL", ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.gases_table = {
      H2: '100',
      H3: "200",
      H4: '100',
      H5: "200",
      H6: "200",
      H7: "200"
    }
  }
]);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.section_title {
  color: #3983C4;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  /* width: auto; 
        height: auto;  Responsive changes*/
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -o-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.25);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.25);
}
#left_side {
  float: left;
  /* width:65%;
        overflow:hidden;*/
}
#right_side {
  float: right;
  /* width:30%;
        overflow:hidden;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCTRL">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <h4 class="section_title">IEEE</h4>
      <div id="IEEE_box" class="container-fluid box">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="left_side" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <table id="IEE_table_One" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td class="table_element_title">Conditions:</td>
                <td class="box_element_desc">ieeeCondition</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="table_element_title">Recommendation:</td>
                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.Recommendation</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="table_element_title">Sampling Interval:</td>
                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.SamplingInterval</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="table_element_title">TDCG:</td>
                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.TDCG</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="table_element_title">TDCG:</td>
                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.TDCG</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div id="right_side" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <table id="IEE_table_Two" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
              <tr>
                <th class="tools_fault_item_title">Tools</th>
                <th class="tools_fault_item_title">Fault</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">Rogers</td>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">ieee.RogerFault</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">Durenberger</td>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">ieee.GasRatioFault</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">Gas Ratio</td>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">ieee.DoernenburgFault</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table id="IEE_table_Third" class="gases_table table-bordered" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1" style="display: inline-block">
              <tr>
                <th class="gases_table_head_item" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                  {{key}}
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="gases_table_item" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                  <span>
                                        {{value}}
                                    </span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <h4 class="section_title">IEEE</h4>
      <div id="IEEE_box" class="container-fluid box">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="left_side" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <table id="IEE_table_One" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td class="table_element_title">Conditions:</td>
                <td class="box_element_desc">ieeeCondition</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="table_element_title">Recommendation:</td>
                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.Recommendation</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="table_element_title">Sampling Interval:</td>
                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.SamplingInterval</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="table_element_title">TDCG:</td>
                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.TDCG</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="table_element_title">TDCG:</td>
                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.TDCG</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div id="right_side" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <table id="IEE_table_Two" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
              <tr>
                <th class="tools_fault_item_title">Tools</th>
                <th class="tools_fault_item_title">Fault</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">Rogers</td>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">ieee.RogerFault</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">Durenberger</td>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">ieee.GasRatioFault</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">Gas Ratio</td>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">ieee.DoernenburgFault</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table id="IEE_table_Third" class="gases_table table-bordered" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1" style="display: inline-block">
              <tr>
                <th class="gases_table_head_item" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                  {{key}}
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="gases_table_item" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                  <span>
                                        {{value}}
                                    </span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <h4 class="section_title">IEEE</h4>
      <div id="IEEE_box" class="container-fluid box">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="left_side" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <table id="IEE_table_One" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td class="table_element_title">Conditions:</td>
                <td class="box_element_desc">ieeeCondition</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="table_element_title">Recommendation:</td>
                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.Recommendation</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="table_element_title">Sampling Interval:</td>
                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.SamplingInterval</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="table_element_title">TDCG:</td>
                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.TDCG</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="table_element_title">TDCG:</td>
                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.TDCG</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div id="right_side" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <table id="IEE_table_Two" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
              <tr>
                <th class="tools_fault_item_title">Tools</th>
                <th class="tools_fault_item_title">Fault</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">Rogers</td>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">ieee.RogerFault</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">Durenberger</td>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">ieee.GasRatioFault</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">Gas Ratio</td>
                <td class="tools_fault_item">ieee.DoernenburgFault</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table id="IEE_table_Third" class="gases_table table-bordered" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1" style="display: inline-block">
              <tr>
                <th class="gases_table_head_item" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                  {{key}}
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="gases_table_item" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                  <span>
                                        {{value}}
                                    </span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand the Bootstrap concept first: your content gets overlapped because there is minimum width requirement for any containers - it gets exceeded in your case. In bootstrap DOM is divided into 12 parts so that on a sum your containers must equal 12 eg:

```
<div class="col-md-6"></div><div class="col-md-6"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div><div class="col-md-4"></div><div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

Use like this

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
            <h4 class="section_title">IEEE</h4>
            <div id="IEEE_box" class="container-fluid box">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="left_side" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <table id="IEE_table_One" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td class="table_element_title">Conditions:</td>
                                <td class="box_element_desc">ieeeCondition</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="table_element_title">Recommendation:</td>
                                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.Recommendation</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="table_element_title">Sampling Interval:</td>
                                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.SamplingInterval</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="table_element_title">TDCG:</td>
                                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.TDCG</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="table_element_title">TDCG:</td>
                                <td class="box_element_desc">ieee.TDCG</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right_side" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <table id="IEE_table_Two" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <th class="tools_fault_item_title">Tools</th>
                                <th class="tools_fault_item_title">Fault</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tools_fault_item">Rogers</td>
                                <td class="tools_fault_item">ieee.RogerFault</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tools_fault_item">Durenberger</td>
                                <td class="tools_fault_item">ieee.GasRatioFault</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tools_fault_item">Gas Ratio</td>
                                <td class="tools_fault_item">ieee.DoernenburgFault</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <table id="IEE_table_Third" class="gases_table table-bordered" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1" style="display: inline-block">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <!-- ngRepeat: (key,value) in gases_table track by $index --><th class="gases_table_head_item ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                                    H2
                                </th><!-- end ngRepeat: (key,value) in gases_table track by $index --><th class="gases_table_head_item ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                                    H3
                                </th><!-- end ngRepeat: (key,value) in gases_table track by $index --><th class="gases_table_head_item ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                                    H4
                                </th><!-- end ngRepeat: (key,value) in gases_table track by $index --><th class="gases_table_head_item ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                                    H5
                                </th><!-- end ngRepeat: (key,value) in gases_table track by $index --><th class="gases_table_head_item ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                                    H6
                                </th><!-- end ngRepeat: (key,value) in gases_table track by $index --><th class="gases_table_head_item ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                                    H7
                                </th><!-- end ngRepeat: (key,value) in gases_table track by $index -->
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <!-- ngRepeat: (key,value) in gases_table track by $index --><td class="gases_table_item ng-scope" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                                    <span class="ng-binding">
                                        100
                                    </span>
                                </td><!-- end ngRepeat: (key,value) in gases_table track by $index --><td class="gases_table_item ng-scope" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                                    <span class="ng-binding">
                                        200
                                    </span>
                                </td><!-- end ngRepeat: (key,value) in gases_table track by $index --><td class="gases_table_item ng-scope" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                                    <span class="ng-binding">
                                        100
                                    </span>
                                </td><!-- end ngRepeat: (key,value) in gases_table track by $index --><td class="gases_table_item ng-scope" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                                    <span class="ng-binding">
                                        200
                                    </span>
                                </td><!-- end ngRepeat: (key,value) in gases_table track by $index --><td class="gases_table_item ng-scope" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                                    <span class="ng-binding">
                                        200
                                    </span>
                                </td><!-- end ngRepeat: (key,value) in gases_table track by $index --><td class="gases_table_item ng-scope" ng-repeat="(key,value) in gases_table track by $index">
                                    <span class="ng-binding">
                                        200
                                    </span>
                                </td><!-- end ngRepeat: (key,value) in gases_table track by $index -->
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
<div class="col-lg-6">'your content'</div>
//You cant fit all in a single row
<div class="col-lg-10">'your content'</div>
```

Comment: so what is the right partition in my case so there won't be an overlapping problem?

Comment: and what about the formula:  target/context = result
How do I implement it on my current example,can you demonstrate it?

Comment: I have given only for larger devices, add sm and md classes too upto your requirement. Its better if you do basic samples or study bootstrap gird concept http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: hat about the formula: target/context = result How do I implement it on my current example,can you demonstrate it?